# Deletion of node at end of linked list C++

Tags: c++, linked-list, stack

Hope you had a nice day/night so far, I'm trying to implement a stack using linked list, and I pretty much know how to insert an item at the end of the list. I'm trying to delete a node at the end of the list, but I can't do it properly.

```
void Pop(){

    Node* temp1 = head;
    Node* temp2 = NULL;

    while(temp1 != NULL){
        temp2 = temp1;
        temp1 = temp1->next;
    }
    delete temp1;
    temp2->next = NULL;

}
```

That was my code to delete the node at the end of the list. I played around with a lot but this didn't make the program stop executing or print out numbers infinitely.

So I "pushed" 3 numbers and printed them in between each "push" and "popped" twice and printed the results in between as well. But the output is like this:

```
1
1 2
1 2 3
1 2 3
1 2 3
```

What I would want to happen is this:

```
1
1 2
1 2 3
1 2
1
```

Thanks in advance!`:D`

Comment: Run it in a debugger with a breakpoint just before `delete temp1`; check what `temp1` is.

Comment: You could have checked what temp1 is pointing to using debugger, before posting this question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your loop spins until `temp1` becomes `NULL`, and then you are trying to delete it. So you are actually deleting... nothing.

1. Check if `temp1` is not `NULL`
2. Check if `temp1->next` is not `NULL`
3. Check if `temp2` is not `NULL`
4. Set `head` to `NULL` if `temp1 == head`

   ```
   void Pop(void) {
       Node *t = head, *p = NULL;
       if (t == NULL) {
           return;
       }
       while (t->next != NULL) {
           p = t;
           t = t->next;
       }
       delete t;
       if (p != NULL) {
           p->next = NULL;
       } else {
           head = NULL;
       }
   }
   ```

Comment: Yeah I realised that it stopped at null which was the problem. This helped, thanks!

Answer (score 3):

By the time `temp1` is null, it means you've hit the end of the list. You'll need to stop when the check for `temp1.next` is `null`.

```
if (!head)
   return; // or throw ... no element to pop

while(temp1->next){
    temp2 = temp1;
    temp1 = temp1->next;
}

if (temp2) // If the element had a single element, we've just popped head.
  temp2->next = NULL;
else
  head = null;

delete temp1;
```

As an aside, you'll want to add robustness to guard against a list with a null head or a single element.

Comment: Ah yeah thanks now I realised that it should've been temp1->next in the while loop. And this also taught me some things. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The other answers already correctly point out the bug in your code (the loop doesn't terminate early enough). I just wanted to mention that you could avoid the need for any `tempN` pointer variables by using pointers-to-pointers. I.e. instead of pointing to the nodes, you point to the references to nodes:

```
void pop( Node **n ) {
    if ( !*n ) {
        return;
    }

    while ( (*n)->next ) {
        n = &(*n)->next;
    }

    delete *n;
    *n = 0;
}
```

Comment: I see, I'm not exactly sure how to use pointer-to-pointers, but I'll read up on it and make sure it'll be able to use it, thanks.